# How to change the font size in the button?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, material-ui

How can I change the font size of the text inside the button?
**I am using it with React for Front End JS**

```
var Button2 = window['material-ui'].Button; 

<Button2 variant="contained" >
    Search 
</Button2>
```

Comment: Please specify what language and what have you tried so far

Comment: Thx i have updated my question .

Comment: Do you want to change it dynamically (e.g. when the state's changed), or you're just asking how to specify `font-size` on that button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use following convention:

```
<Button2 style={{ fontSize: '63px' }} variant="contained" >
          Search 
</Button2>
```